# Override jQuery style value

Tags: jquery, coding-style, overriding, attributes

To resolve a jQuery slideDown/Up problem, I had to change one line in the jQuery file.

I changed line 5738 from
this.elem.style.display = "block";
to
this.elem.style.display = "inline-block";

The block attribute messed up my lists when using slideDown/Up/Toggle. slideDown changes my list from display:inline to display:block during execution, and then back to display: inline again. It would be much better if it was inline (or inline-block) all the way. Is there a way to override the value stated above from my html page, or do I have to stick with my modified jQuery file?

It would be nice if I could override the style attribute *only* when I perform
$('.gallery_container li:gt(4)').slideToggle();

Here's the code:
http://90.230.237.71/gandhi.html

Comment: What *was* the sliding problem?

Comment: My list appeared vertical when sliding, due to display: block. I want them to appear horizontal.

It's when pushing "Show/hide gallery", the sliding is performed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  $('#as_test').slideUp(300,function(){ 
      $('#your_lists_id').css('display','inline');
    //$('#your_lists_id').css('display','inline-block');
  });
```

There is a callback function for slideUp and slideDown , it gets called once the the slideUp or slideDown finishes its job , and hence you can easily give whetever you wanna do once your slide action is over.